# Is there a way to know what version of Exchange a users mailbox is on via AD?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013

In Active Directory there is a property against a user called "homeMDB" That will give me the users exchange database, but is there a way to know if the user is on exchange 2013 through Active Directory?

Comment: If you know the Database Name and what server there are on and all different then can work it out. never seen a easy way.

Comment: Not from ADUC, but you could use Powershell to query Exchange and get the info.

Comment: Would look that way from powershell; Get-Mailbox | Sort database, name | Format-Table name, database

Comment: I'm curious why?  It sounds like you are wanting to know what kind of car Sebastian Vettel races based on the sponsorships on his fire suit.  You're obviously a developer, so what's your end goal here and why are starting from this property in AD?

Comment: @TheCleaner I'm using EWS to do some synchronisation of messages but the methods I'm using are only supported in Exch 2013. The reason I wanted to know if I could get the info from AD was because I didn't want to install the exchange Powershell extensions on the server where this is running. querying AD does not require any extensions installed and can use standard .NET API's

Answer (score -1):

Probably the best reply would be:

"The current proposal for a solution is to use "get-mailboxstatistics  | fl Displayname, ServerName" or "get-mailbox | get-mailboxstatistics |fl Displayname, ServerName". If Displayname is too ambiguous, you may use Identity or PrimarySMTPAddress instead."

Read the full explanation [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appssrv/archive/2014/03/10/get-mailbox-does-not-reflect-the-correct-servername-for-mailboxes-on-databases-for-a-dag.aspx).